# openJDK build on solaris 10: Format error: shdr table truncated

Tags: java, solaris-10

I am trying to build openJDK8 in Solaris 10.
Solaris:
uname -a
o/p: SunOS xxxx 5.10 Generic_148889-05 i86pc i386 i86pc

I followed the steps mentioned in https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html#solaris

Installed necessary packages to build openJDK such as Mercurial, gmake, freetype, cups and xRender from openCSW.

I've downloaded jdk8 from Mercurials and got source.
bash ./configure is success. After that when i run **gmake all** getting below error.

```
Making libjvm_db.so
Opening 'libjvm_db.so' for update
No SHF_ALLOC flags needed to be cleared.
Done with 'libjvm_db.so'
Computing CRC for 'libjvm_db.debuginfo'
Opening 'libjvm_db.so' for update
Adding ELF data for new section name
Adding ELF data for debug_info_path value
Saving updates to 'libjvm_db.so'
Done updating 'libjvm_db.so'
/usr/ccs/bin/nm: g1CollectedHeap.o: Format error: shdr table truncated
ld: warning: symbol '__JvmOffsets' has differing types:
        (file JvmOffsets.o type=OBJT; file dtrace.o type=FUNC);
ld: warning: symbol 'CodeCache::_heap' has differing types:
        (file codeCache.o type=OBJT; file dtrace.o type=FUNC);
ld: warning: symbol 'BufferBlob::__vtbl' has differing types:
        (file codeBlob.o type=OBJT; file dtrace.o type=FUNC);
ld: fatal: file g1CollectedHeap.o: Format error: shdr table truncated
ld: fatal: file processing errors. No output written to libjvm.so
gmake[6]: *** [libjvm.so] Error 2
gmake[5]: *** [the_vm] Error 2
gmake[4]: *** [product] Error 2
gmake[3]: *** [generic_build2] Error 2
gmake[2]: *** [product] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [/export/home/openjdk/build/solaris-x86_64-normal-server-release/hotspot/_hotspot.timestamp] Error 2
gmake: *** [hotspot-only] Error 2
```

Can anyone point out how to resolve this error.

Comment: I might take a crack at this given I'm stuck at home this week due to COVID-19.  I'd start by looking into what's presumably the `dtrace.c` file, finding the symbols in question there, and seeing how they are defined for different platforms.  I am assuming that the symbols in `dtrace.c` do have different symbols for different platforms, but there might also be different `dtrace.c` files for different platforms.